# Bar code scanner will not work with Google App Script and IFRAME (Google Web App)

Tags: iframe, google-apps-script

Currently we have a Google Web App that was created from an html form.  It works great on a desktop computer or phone when testing the link given by the 'publish your web app'.  If you load the link into a barcode scanner app, the barcode will not go into the input boxes.  The fail error is it can't find the input box.  Emailed the app developer, they said it was because the page was loaded with IFRAMES.  I have tried to force the page to load without the frames, but I am not very familiar with Google App Scripting to really understand how to do this.  I have added a  to the html file and also tried to change the code below to work.

Here  is what my doGet() looks like:

```
function doGet()
{
var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('index2');
html.addMetaTag('viewport','width-device-width,initial-scale=1');
html.addMetaTag('apple-mobile-web-app-capable','content=yes');
return html.setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL)
}
```

The input boxes are simple:

```
<input type="text" name="box1" value="">
```

Suggestions/explanations would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: I've had the same problem. I did some more testing today. If I created html in script editor myself then I can't scan data into the text boxes.  I can type it in or paste it in but I can't scan it in.  If I create a Google Form and attach it to my spreadsheet and go to the url given me in the Deploy as Web App Dialog then all is fine and I can scan data into the form.  I tried embedding it with the text provide in Form/Embed Form in a Web Page then I again can't scan data into the form again.  So the only thing that works is a Google Form that's not embedded in another website.

Comment: Currently we have a regular Google form (not an html form/web app) that works with the barcode scanner app fine.  We can pull the html code out of the Google file, place it on a webserver and link back to it through the barcode scanner app - and it works fine (but the form won't send information back to the Google sheet because it isn't linked). But using the html form as a web app from within Google app scripts just doesn't work.  There must be some setting, some way for it to work.